# openCL without Nvidia CUDA SDK

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I have an Nvidia CUDA support GPU device installed. My requirement is to run an openCL application on my GPU. Can I do it independent from Nvidia Cuda SDK?

Comment: Q: Can you run OpenCL with NVIDIA?  A: Sure.  Q: Can I do it without installing any NVIDIA SDK dependencies?  A: At a minimum, you must do this:  http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/ (all platforms), http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/ (Windows).  Here's a link for Ubutnu: http://orbigo.net/2012/07/installing-nvidia-opencl-cuda-sdk-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/.  Q: What platform are you on?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm working on linux platform. Is cuda-toolkit enough to run openCL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need NVIDIA GPU drivers installed to *run* binaries that have OpenCL support. libOpenCL.so is included with the drivers.

In order to compile the applications you will also need OpenCL headers. Those may come from CUDA Toolkit, from a separate package (like `opencl-headers` for Ubuntu), or you can just download them from the [Khronos site](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/) (keep in mind that NVIDIA implements version 1.1 of OpenCL specification).